# Rename columns on the fly during lapply tidy

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to name/rename columns of a data frame / tibble on the fly during the use of
lapply operations.
For example:

```
df <- tibble(names = rep("abc",100), 
              number1 = sample(1:1000, size = 100),
              number2 = sample(10:900, size = 100),
              char_1 = sample(c("a","b","c"), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
              number3 = round(rnorm(100, mean = 100)))
files_names <- df %>% 
  distinct(char_1 ) %>% 
  deframe %>% as.list()
names(files_names) <- files_names
lapply()
df_a <- df %>% filter(char_1 == "a")

lst_files <- lapply(files_names, function(x){
 df %>% filter(char_1 == x) %>% 
    mutate(str_glue("{x}_num3") = number3 +100)
})
```

> `Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   " df %>% filter(char_1 == x) %>% 
>       mutate(str_glue("{x}_num3") ="
>   })
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

In this example, I use mutate function and of course, I get an error,

but generally, I need to use
select/rename or mutate operations inside the lapply

with preferably the combination of str_glue function or 
paste. 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `:=` for assignment here.  With `tidyverse`, we can use `map` to loop over the `list` elements (similar to `lapply` from `base R`), then after `filter`ing the rows based on the unique elements passed into `map`, create a column with `mutate` on the fly with the assignment operator (`:=`), by passing the string and evaluate (`!!`).  The `str_c` does similar action as `paste` from `base R` except that its behavior is sligtly different when there are `NA`s

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(files_names, ~ 
       df %>% 
          filter(char_1 == .x) %>%
          mutate(!!str_c(.x, "_num3") := number3 + 100))
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a small explanation?

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `lapply` over `files_names`, `subset` `df` based on it, add a new column with `transform` and assign names using `setNames`

```
lapply(files_names, function(x) setNames(transform(subset(df, char_1 == x), 
           temp = number3 + 100), c(names(df), paste0(x,"_num3"))))

#$c
#   names number1 number2 char_1 number3 c_num3
#1    abc     463     680      c     100    200
#2    abc     244      76      c     100    200
#3    abc      14     672      c     100    200
#4    abc     603     657      c     101    201
#5    abc     709      83      c      99    199
#....
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(names = rep("abc",100), 
         number1 = sample(1:1000, size = 100),
         number2 = sample(10:900, size = 100),
         char_1 = sample(c("a","b","c"), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
         number3 = round(rnorm(100, mean = 100)))
```